# different server name for kerberos authentication

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

i have configured kerberos authentication when accessing to file server.
there is no need for logging in when i map drive and acccess to the file server
Just a curious question, if i can add additional server name to be used for authentication

for example.

currently my file server name is server01
when i map network drive through server01 / IP address, there is no issue.
when i tried to access through a server name server02, then i get an error in mapping the drive.

is there any way i can do this by allowing multiple server name to be allowed for kerberos authentication ?

thanks in advance for any advise

Answer (score 0):

You can map as many file shares as possible you want with Kerberos authentication on a Windows domain joined system if the file servers hosting the file shares are joined to the same domain as the client Windows system accessing them.

Thus, you may have multiple file servers in your domain environment but they all should be joined to the AD domain for the Kerberos authentication to work successfully and let the users accessing and mapping the file shares authenticate through it as Kerberos needs a KDC (Key Distribution Center) due to which Active Directory authentication is required.

Please find the below dependencies for Kerberos authentication to work successfully: -

1. Operating System --> Later then Windows 2000 for client and Windows 2003
2. TCP/IP Network Connectivity --> Should exist between DC, client, and the target server
3. Domain System --> DNS must be functioning and accessible for the client
4. Active Directory Domain --> Necessary to use Kerberos authentication
5. Time Service --> Time source should be same and synchronized on all the network computers
6. Service Principal Names --> Kerberos authentication needs to have an SPN set for it so that clients can identify the service on the network

Also, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc780469(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) document for more details.

Comment: thank you very much for the comment @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT. 1 question regarding this, if i am able to use the same SPN for 2 different servers? i dont need the A -record to be configured, i only need the SPN to be able to perform the authentication in the server when i send it over.

Comment: Kerberos authentication is a service that is hosted by Active Directory DC due to which setting SPN for it is enough as it will redirect the kerberos authentication requests to the SOA, i.e., PDC(Primary Domain Controller) for resolution and as for other specific services that are used in your environment, for example, ADFS or some application specific server, it will need an A record in internal DNS server for redirection and local naming resolution.